# EXCEL IF function with AND and OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help, not great at Excel.

If cell `AS25`, `AT25` or `AU25` equals 1, and cell `AQ25` equals `yes`, then cell `AV25` should have a value of 1.

Currently, I have tried both formulas below, but I always get 1 in cell `AV25`, regardless if there is anything in `AS25`, `AT25` or `AU25`.

```
=IF(OR(AND(AS25="1",AT25="1",AU25="1"),AQ25="yes"),1,"") 

=IF(AND(OR(AS25="1",AT25="1",AU25="1"),AQ25="yes"),1,"")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second formula looks good to me for this task.  First formula is incorrect based on your description.  If it's not working for you, please edit your question to include sample data and expected results.

Comment: Try to read about OR and AND operators - then try to implement it in Excel. Anyways, your second formula is the correct one in this case

Comment: Don't wrap true numbers in quotes.

Comment: You could shorten it a little by multiplication:  `=IF(AND(AS25*AT25*AU25=1,AQ25="yes"),1,"")`

Comment: Both your original formulae were incorrect as you were closing the AND() too early - see PeterT : the AND() is only closed after checking cell AQ25... also Jeeped's point about numbers in quotes.